# What would Chrome display if my front-end crashes in production?

Tags: reactjs, crash, frontend, production-environment

My app works fine until I hit a specific link in my app. For example, when a user hits [www.xxxx.com](http://www.xxxx.com) everything runs fine. However, if a user hits www.xxx/cart.com, my app crashes and React tells me that in production the error will not be displayed. So what will be displayed? A white sheet?

Of course, it crashes because my component needs preview elements to be displayed in the cart. What could be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [error-boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) to catch errors in your react application and display fallback content

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed.

Comment: Thank you! I will read about error-boundaries. I was thinking to redirect them to my home page.